# Correctness of the definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Consider the integral

\begin{eqnarray*}
I & = & \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})}\\
 & = & \int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})}
\end{eqnarray*}

Use the substitutions $u=-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$ and $v=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$
into first and second integrals respectively.

\begin{eqnarray*}
= & -{\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{0}}\frac{du}{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & +{\displaystyle \int}_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{(1+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Noticing that

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{du}{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=-\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{du}{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{(1+u)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray*}
and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{(1+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{\frac{v}{2}}}= & {\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}}\frac{dv}{(1+v)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-v)^{\frac{1}{2}}} & -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dv}{(1+v)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-v)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally leading to  the result

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})} & ={\displaystyle \int}_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}} & -\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}

The value of the integral is 2. But the R.H.S. seem to be difference of two divergent integrals. Can someone suggest whether the derivation is still consistent and valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})}dx= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}(1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}})}dx$$

Above we Used $\displaystyle \bullet \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx\;,$ If $f(-x) = f(x)$

Now Put $x=\sin \phi\;,$ Then $dx = \cos\phi d\phi$ and Changing limit, We get

So $$\displaystyle I = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos \phi}{\cos \phi\cdot (1+\cos \phi)}d\phi = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\cos \phi}{\sin^2 \phi}d\phi$$

So $$\displaystyle I = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\csc^2 \phi-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\csc\phi\cdot \cot \phi d\phi = -2\left[\cot \phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+2\left[\csc \phi \right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = 2\cdot \lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\cot (a)+2-2\cdot \lim_{b\rightarrow 0}\csc (b)$$

<strike>Yes the given Integral is Divergent</strike>.
By applying L'Hospital's rule , we evaluate the limit $$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0 } \left( \cot a - \csc a \right) = 0 $$,

So we get

$$ I = 2 $$

Comment: The wikipedia link on improper integrals is useful [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Comment: I am only puzzled by the fact that L.H.S has limit but the R.H.S. is clearly diverging. Why this discrepancy ??  What causes the problem here?

Comment: Dear @juantheron, thanks for the answer.